# inserir registro de xml mais data em uma tabela temporaria

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, xml, sql-insert

queria fazer esse select porém nao consigo

```
>     DECLARE @XML XML
>     SET @XML = 
>     '<rows> <row> <tracking> JU148345357BR</tracking> </row> <row> <tracking> PM318855649BR</tracking> </row></rows>'
>     insert into #tracking3 (tracking, data) values (SELECT Tbl.Col.value('tracking[1]', 'varchar(13)') as tracking FROM  
> @xml.nodes('//row') Tbl(Col), getDate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tens aqui a solução. Mas falta criar a tabela temporária, sabes como criar?

```
DECLARE @hDoc int

DECLARE @XML XML
        SET @XML = '<rows> <row> <tracking> JU148345357BR</tracking> </row> <row> <tracking> PM318855649BR</tracking> </row></rows>'
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML 
        INSERT INTO #tracking3 
        (tracking, data)
        SELECT 
            XMLTable.tracking,
            GETDATE()
        FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'rows/row',2)   
        WITH (
             tracking  varchar(max)
            ) XMLTable
    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```